# Flatlist Load More

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm having a trouble figuring out the solution to my problem. Load more is working when the content covers the whole screen but if the content doesn't occupy the screen it stuck in loading.

```
  onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
  onEndReached={() => fetchMoreData()}
```

[data content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWcCZ.png)

is there a way to load another 10 items if the content doesn't occupy the whole screen? thank you so much for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can add `isFetchMore` flag default is `true`, when fetching data, if the length of data = 0, it means no more data from the server. You can use this flag to stop loadmore

Comment: fetchMoreDatanot triggered after the 10 items, you need to scroll down for it to trigger

Comment: can you show fully your code?